# React Router Lazy Component isn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading

So this works:

```
import Page from 'components/Page';
...

render() {
   return (
     <Route render={props => <Page {...props}/>}/>
   );
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
const Cmp = lazy(() => import('components/Page'));
...

render() {
   return (
     <Route render={props => <Cmp {...props}/>}/>
   );
}
```

React 16.8.6
React Router 5.0.0

I get this:

```
The above error occurred in one of your React components:
    in Unknown (at configured.route.js:41)
    in Route (at configured.route.js:41)
    in ConfiguredRoute (created by Context.Consumer)
    ...rest of stack trace
```

Can anyone see what stupid thing I am doing here?

Comment: dont you need to use suspense with a fallback? Id guess that the Cmp component isn't instantiated yet so you have a object spread on a deferred? Can you debug what Cmp is when rendering / failing?

Comment: Answer that @JohnRuddell - you need to define `fallback` - if you wrap the component in `<Suspense>` but don't define `fallback` it fails the same way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Referencing the [**React Docs on code splitting**](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting), the recommendation is to use `Suspense` with a defined `fallback` so you have something to render in place of the components when they haven't loaded.

```
// Direct paste from https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./routes/About'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Suspense should be a parent of the `<Route>` elements that use `lazy`

Comment: For the record, I knew Suspense with fallback was a recommendation, I never knew it errored out (maybe development mode only?) if you didn't provide it.

Comment: And by "it" above, I meant it errors out if you provide the Suspense component, but not the `fallback` prop

Answer (score 4):

I updated the version of react and this error started to show up because I forgot to also update the react-dom package version, once I did that everything worked fine.