# React Lazy loading import failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component looks something like this, of course with a few unimportant details omitted:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const DialogBox = React.lazy(() => import('./DialogBox'));

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    answer: state.answers[state.stepper][ownProps.obj.ID]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { }


class FlexiblePopupSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <DialogBox />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(FlexiblePopupSelect));
```

When I replace the `const DialogBox = React.lazy(() => import('./DialogBox'));` line with a normal `import DialogBox from './DialogBox'`, everything works fine. I followed [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) from React's site, but with no success. Where did I go wrong here?

EDIT:

There was no real error message, it just gives me a bunch of error messages that say "The above error occurred in one of your React components" but it never gives me any error message above.

I am using React 16.8.6 with Create-React-App handling the Webpack side of things.

EDIT 2:

After a bit of fiddling, I found out that the fix was using the `<Suspense>` component from react like so:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Suspense>
    <DialogBox />
  </Suspense>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: what was the error message? which versions of React and Webpack are you using?

Comment: @Aprillion see my above edits for this information

Comment: [react router lazy component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56247555/1176601) looks related if you are using Router... if not, what version of `react-scripts` (installed by create react app)? is the line number for the error message on the dynamic import or different line?

Comment: Great job @NicholasDomenichini I saw the update right after I posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your lazily component with [React.Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) by providing the fallback component to show. (such as a message or a loading gif etc).

You can safely replace `React.Fragment` with `React.Suspense`.

```
class FlexiblePopupSelect extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading dialog box...</div>}>
        <DialogBox />
      </React.Suspense>
    )
  }
}
```

For more info, check out [Code-Splitting > Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense) documentation.